# I want to get JSON exception instead of 505 default exception

Tags: java, rest, tomcat8, postman

I am creating messenger application in java 8 and using REST.
I have added set off messages in my app.

I want to get a JSON response as User defined exception instead of default exception thrown by apache tomcat.

For example i have two messages in my Map with id =1 and 2.
If i try to GET the messages by providing messageid 67, it should throw the exception.

It is throwing exception in HTML format by apache tomcat which is not my requirement, instead i want user defined exception in JSON format.

I am getting the Custom message defined by me but not in JSON format.

I am using Postman.

here is my code.

### MessageService.java

```
package com.diwakar.messenger.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.diwakar.messenger.database.DatabaseClass;
import com.diwakar.messenger.exception.DataNotFoundException;
import com.diwakar.messenger.model.Message;

public class MessageService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages = DatabaseClass.getMessages();

    public MessageService() {
        messages.put(1L, new Message(1L, "Hello World!", "Diwakar"));
        messages.put(2L, new Message(2L, "Hello Jersey!", "Diwakar"));
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessagesForYear(int year) {
        List<Message> messagesForYear = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (Message message : messages.values()) {
            cal.setTime(message.getCreated());
            if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year) {
                messagesForYear.add(message);
            }
        }
        return messagesForYear;
    }


    public List<Message> getAllMessagesPaginated(int start, int size) {
        List<Message> list = new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
        if (start + size > list.size()){
            return new ArrayList<Message>();
        }
        return list.subList(start, start + size);
    }


    public Message getMessage(long id) {
        Message message =  messages.get(id);
        if (message == null) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Message with id : " + id + " not found. ");
        }
        return message;
    }

    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        message.setId(messages.size() + 1);
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message updateMessage(Message message) {
        if (message.getId() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }else {
            messages.put(message.getId(), message);
            return message;
        }
    }

    public Message removeMessage(long id) {
        return messages.remove(id);
    }


}
```

### DataNotFoundException.java

```
package com.diwakar.messenger.exception;

public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

### DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.java

```
package com.diwakar.messenger.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.diwakar.messenger.model.ErrorMessage;

@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException ex) {

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(), 404, "http://www.google.com");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).build();

    }
}
```

### ErrorMessage.java

```
package com.diwakar.messenger.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorMessage {

    private String errorMessage;
    private int errorCode;
    private String documentation; 

    public ErrorMessage() {

    }

    public ErrorMessage(String errorMessage, int errorCode, String documentation){
        super();
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.documentation = documentation;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }
    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public String getDocumentation() {
        return documentation;
    }
    public void setDocumentation(String documentation) {
        this.documentation = documentation;
    }



}
```

[Messages reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9P0P.png)

[exception thrown by apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExPr5.png)

Comment: I am getting my custom exception but in html format not in JSON format. can anyone please help me on that. Added images also for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I got the answer...

Instead of using com.diwakar.messenger.resources, we can use com.diwakar.messenger or (com.diwakar.messenger.resources and com.diwakar.messenger.exception) both.

What this init-parm jersey.config.server.provider.packages says is that Jersey should scan the named package for @Path annotated resource class and @Provider annotated provider classes and register them.

we only have the resources package com.diwakar.messenger.resources listed, but ExceptionMapper is in a different package. The default behavior is to scan recursively, meaning sub-packages also. So if we write com.diwakar.messenger instead,you would hit both the resources package and the exceptions package. Or we could list both packages, separated by comma or semi-colon. Either way would work

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.diwakar.messenger</param-value> 
            <!-- <param-value>com.diwakar.messenger.resources</param-value> -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[Custom Exception thrown as JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hIa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to return a valid 200 response with the payload being the serialized exception data, then your client code would need to be able to tell the difference between a 'valid' 200 and an 'error' 200, maybe a flag in the payload as well.

I'm not 100% with java and tomcat but hard throwing a server exception will generally create a 500 response that gets wrapped however the REST framework in question decides to do it, usually without sensitive exception data. The only way to take control is to return the 200 response with custom payload data.

Also remember that how you do it could expose the exception details to the client (javascript) which you usually do NOT want.

Comment: Thanks Paul for response, i have added source code too. and images also. But is there any other way to do this in java.

Comment: Don't throw the exception, you are turning everything over to tomcat at that point and I am not familiar with the exception mapper in java but it does not seem to be called based on the 500 response shown in the error result. It looks like you could just use your exception mapper as is manually to create the result from getMessage...if serialized.

Comment: As per my understanding, MessageService class is throwing exception which is not handled by MessageResource getMessage() method, in that case 500 response thrown by Tomcat(which is default behaviour).

Comment: As per my understanding, MessageService class is throwing exception which is not handled by MessageResource getMessage() method, in that case 500 response thrown by Tomcat(which is default behaviour). Exception Mapper  does that thing, whenever exception is thrown Jax-rs looks for it  and pass to overloaded method toResponse() and we can provide our custom based response as per our needs.In this particular message not sure why it is not going in that particular method (As i have debug also).

Comment: But as per your query, for testing and learning purposes  i want to see how thrown exceptions can be handled and custom exceptions can be thrown in  json format.

Comment: Anyway thanks @Paul for your time and response, I got the answer and also mentioned the reason on the same post for the same